# magento 1.9 THE UPLOAD ICON NOT SHOW IN CHROME

Tags: magento-1.9, upload

The **upload icon** and **browse icon** not showing in chrome
I have`nt this problem in firefox
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, flash is disabled in the browser. Turn it ON using below steps:

While you are on your store

- Click on HTTP or https in the browser address bar
- Look for Flash option in the list
- Set its value to 'Always allow for this site'